# How can I add a text box beside the label for checkbox using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox, textbox, label

How can I add a text box beside the label for checkbox using jquery mobile? It should be in one line (checkbox --> label (for checkbox) --> textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a label in the same line as its referencing element, like for example:

> My legend    [ ] Checkbox label

you may want to try using field containers, with `data-role="fieldcontain"`.

For example:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Agree to the terms:</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" class="custom" />
        <label for="checkbox-2">I agree</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The code above will give you:

> Agree to the terms:   [] I agree

**Check the online doc for more information:** http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/checkboxes/

---

Now, if you want to several elements on one line (= several elements in different columns), I mean more than just a label and its element, you may wanna check the jQuery Mobile's `Layout grids`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/content/content-grids.html

---

Considering your example case, I think you may want to try to use a combination of the 2 methods above. So, you may try something like this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">

    <!-- FIRST COLUMN -->
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>Agree to the terms:</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" class="custom" />
                <label for="checkbox-2">I agree</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SECOND COLUMN -->
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps.